# Tensorflow: `tf.reshape((), (0))` works fine in eager mode but ValueError in Graph mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

As the title, the function `tf.reshape((), (0))` works perfectly fine in eager mode. But when I use it in Graph mode, it returns:
`ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for '{{node Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](Reshape/tensor, Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [0], [].`

Can anyone help me with the work-around of this function please. You can reproduce this error [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PLYhUfVro-CwjQA5jvIZtWngqRWcBI5Q?usp=sharing). I want to recreate this [piece of code](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/blob/main/torchaudio/models/emformer.py#L783) (initialization of `mems`) in Tensorflow's graph mode. Thanks in advance!!

**Edit**: Since I want to clarify my use case, I want to convert this PyTorch `torch.empty(0)` function to Tensorflow (work fine in both eager mode and graph mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be related to this [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46776). Try something like this:

```
@tf.function
def test_graph():
    x = tf.reshape((), (0, ))
    return x

b = test_graph()
b
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(0,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([], dtype=float32)>
```